# Как выровнять меню по центру?

Tags: html, css, меню

```css
ul {
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0px;
    padding-left: 0px;
 margin-top: 30px;


    .menu {
 text-decoration: none;
 background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.0);
 color: #000000;
 padding: 10px;
 font-family: Comic Sans, Comic Sans MS, cursive;
 border-radius: 5px;
 -moz-transition: all 0.3s 0.01s ease;
 -o-transition: all 0.3s 0.01s ease;
 -webkit-transition: all 0.3s 0.01s ease;
 line-height:5px;
 font-size: 25px;
 padding-right: 35px;
 padding-left: 35px;}

    .menu:hover {
 background-color: #D446FF;}

 
    .menu_li {
 float: left;}
```

```html
    <body>
     <div id="menu_conteiner">
            <nav id="menu_nav">
                <ul>
        <li class="menu_li"><a href="#m1" class="menu"> Меню_1 </a></li>
        <li class="menu_li"><a href="#m2" class="menu"> Меню_2 </a></li>
        <li class="menu_li"><a href="#m3" class="menu"> Меню_3 </a></li>
                    <li class="menu_li"><a href="#m4" class="menu"> Меню_4 </a></li>
     <li class="menu_li"><a href="#m5" class="menu"> Меню_5 </a></li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
        </div>
    </body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Например вот так:

```css
ul {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0px;
  padding-left: 0px;
  margin-top: 30px;
  text-align: center;
}

.menu {
  text-decoration: none;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.0);
  color: #000000;
  padding: 10px;
  font-family: Comic Sans, Comic Sans MS, cursive;
  border-radius: 5px;
  -moz-transition: all 0.3s 0.01s ease;
  -o-transition: all 0.3s 0.01s ease;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s 0.01s ease;
  line-height: 5px;
  font-size: 25px;
  padding-right: 35px;
  padding-left: 35px;
}

.menu:hover {
  background-color: #D446FF;
}

.menu_li {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="menu_conteiner">
    <nav id="menu_nav">
      <ul>
        <li class="menu_li"><a href="#m1" class="menu"> Меню_1 </a></li>
        <li class="menu_li"><a href="#m2" class="menu"> Меню_2 </a></li>
        <li class="menu_li"><a href="#m3" class="menu"> Меню_3 </a></li>
        <li class="menu_li"><a href="#m4" class="menu"> Меню_4 </a></li>
        <li class="menu_li"><a href="#m5" class="menu"> Меню_5 </a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Спасибо больше!

Comment: Если ответ вам помог, пометьте его ответом